# IntentService in Xamarin PCL Solution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, intentservice

I am busy writing an application where the user needs to capture a lot of images and then they get packaged together with some text data and then they get uploaded to a local server. I want to implement the uploading on the Android platform through an Intent Service but I cannot find a good Xamarin Forms PCL example to show me how.

This is the method where I initialize the Intent to pass to the IntentService:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadAsync(Uri serviceAddress, 
                       CaptureEntity capture, 
                       List<ImageEntity> images)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent uploadIntent = new Intent();
            uploadIntent.PutExtra("serviceAddress", serviceAddress.ToString());
            uploadIntent.PutExtra("captureId", capture.WorkflowId.ToString());
            StartService(uploadIntent);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            App.logger.LogError(DateTime.Now, "Uploader", exc.ToString());
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

And this is the IntentService itself.

```
[Service]
public class ServiceIntent : IntentService
{
    public ServiceIntent() : base("ServiceIntent")
    {

    }

    //[return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Uri serviceAddress = new Uri(intent.GetStringExtra("serviceAddress"));
        Guid captureId = Guid.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("captureId"));
        CaptureEntity capture = new DatabaseConnection_Android().CreateConnection().Query<CaptureEntity>("SELECT * FROM [CaptureEntity]").Single(c => c.WorkflowId == captureId);
        var images = new DatabaseConnection_Android().CreateConnection().Query<ImageEntity>("SELECT * FROM [ImageEntity]").Where(i => i.CaptureEntityId == capture.Id);
        try
        {
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            StringContent strContent = new StringContent(
                                        capture.XmlData,
                                        Encoding.UTF8,
                                        "text/xml");
            IImageHandler handler = new ImageHandler_Droid();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.Headers.Add("workflow", capture.WorkflowId.ToString());
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = serviceAddress;

            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                byte[] imageByte = handler.ReadAllBytes(image.ImagePath);
                ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageByte);
                byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
                content.Add(byteContent, "file", image.ImageName);
            }
            content.Add(strContent, "text/xml");

            request.Content = content;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);

                var response = client.SendAsync(
                                            request,
                                            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;

                var readResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (readResponse == "File uploaded.")
                    MessagingCenter.Send<CaptureEntity, string>(
                        capture,
                        "Completed",
                        "Success");
                else if (readResponse.Contains("An error has occurred."))
                    MessagingCenter.Send<CaptureEntity, string>(
                        capture,
                        "Uploader",
                        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "Failed: {0}",
                        readResponse));
                else
                    MessagingCenter.Send<CaptureEntity, string>(
                        capture,
                        "Uploader",
                        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "Failed: {0}",
                        readResponse));
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webExc)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<string, string>("Uploader", "Failed",
                        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "{0} upload failed.\n{1}",
                        capture.DisplayName,
                        webExc.Message));
        }
        catch (TimeoutException timeExc)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<string, string>("Uploader", "Failed",
                        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "{0} upload failed.\n{1}",
                        capture.DisplayName,
                        timeExc.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<string, string>("Uploader", "Failed",
                        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "{0} upload failed.\n{1}",
                        capture.DisplayName,
                        exc.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong as I am getting the following error when I want to start the service:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Intent` declaration you need to tell the service you want to call

Something like this:

```
var uploadIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ServiceIntent));
```

Note: `this` represents the `Context`.

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments your interface implementation cannot derive from `Activity` class. In order to have access to the `Context` to be able to call the `StartService` method and also create your `Intent` you can make it in two ways:

Using the `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context`:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadAsync(Uri serviceAddress, 
                    CaptureEntity capture, 
                    List<ImageEntity> images)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
            var uploadIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(ServiceIntent));
            uploadIntent.PutExtra("serviceAddress", serviceAddress.ToString());
            uploadIntent.PutExtra("captureId", capture.WorkflowId.ToString());
            context.StartService(uploadIntent);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            App.logger.LogError(DateTime.Now, "Uploader", exc.ToString());
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

If you are using latest versions of Xamarin.Forms this global context was deprecated and they suggest to you local context instead. You can still use it though but in future updates of XF your app might break.

using **CurrentActivity** [plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin):

```
public async Task<bool> UploadAsync(Uri serviceAddress, 
                    CaptureEntity capture, 
                    List<ImageEntity> images)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
            var uploadIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(ServiceIntent));
            uploadIntent.PutExtra("serviceAddress", serviceAddress.ToString());
            uploadIntent.PutExtra("captureId", capture.WorkflowId.ToString());
            context.StartService(uploadIntent);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            App.logger.LogError(DateTime.Now, "Uploader", exc.ToString());
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

This plugin can be installed from nugget and the setup is very straight forward. Basically it gives you access to the current activity and you can use it as your context to call the `IntentService`

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thanks @apineda but I am getting the following error now when I initialize the Intent:Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: The uploadAsync method is called from an interface in my PCL library through dependency injection. I added Activity for this class' inheritance.

Comment: That's where the issue is: Your class is _not_ an `Activity`. Activities when inflated by Android OS they are initialized in a special way. Get the current activity Context (you can use this package https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) and inject it to your UploadService (not the IntentService but the one that call this) and then you can call the currentActivity.StartService(intent); If you get stuck update here I might be able to help

Comment: @GANDA1F Just added an update that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

In Android, we usually use `IntentService` to do asynchronous operator. As we all know, thread is also used to do asynchronous operator. The difference between `IntentService` and `Thread` is `IntentService` is `Service` which belongs to Android Component. So, the priority of `IntentService` is higher than `Thread.`

For example, there is a `ActivityA` which has a `IntentService`, and there is a `ActivityB` which has a `Thread`, both `IntentService` and `Thread` are working, and both `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` are al background `Activity`. Now, if your phone's system doesn't have extra resources, your `ActivityB` will be killed firstly.

## About the Exception:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ComponentName android.content.Context.startService(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

That means you should use `android.content.Context` to call the `StartService` method. In Android, there are three kinds of `Context`. [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). So you can call the `StartService` method in these three classes directly. If you are not in these three classes, you need pass the `Context` to your class, and then use the `Context` to call `StartService`.

> I added Activity for this class' inheritance.

If you do this, your class will be a `Activity`, and you need to register it in your manifiest, add layout for your class, and it should have the lifecycle, and etc. It will not be what you want to get class. In Android, Activity is a Component, not normal class, so you can't inherit it unless you want your class to be a Activity.

### Demo:

I have made a [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/IntentServiceTest) for you,